# React-native run-android always downloads everything

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, gradle, react-native

When I attempt to build and run the basic react-native testapp, the batch process always downloads a ton of components. This takes a tremendous amount of time and seems like a terrible waste of time and bandwidth.

How do I get react native to simply use a cached or existing copy of these components rather than download them from scratch all the time?

I set react-native up as described in the docs on windows 7.

For example:

```
C:\Users\C3\Documents\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat install
Debug...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
................................................................................
......
Unzipping C:\Users\C3\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.10-all\a4w5fzrkeut1ox71xslb49gst\gradle-2.10-all.zip to C:\Users\C3\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.10-all\a4w5fzrkeut1ox71xslb49gst
Download jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.2/gradle-2.1.2.pom
Download jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.1.2/gradle-core-2.1.2.pom
Download jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/2.1.2/builder-2.1.2.pom
Download jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/25.1.2/lint-25.1.2.pom
Download jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.pom
Download jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/2.1.2/gradle-api-2.1.2.pom
Download jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compilerCommon/2.1.2/compilerCommon-2.1.2.pom
Download jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.3/asm-commons-5.0.3.pom
Download jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.core-.7.4.201502262128.pom
Download jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.build/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.build-0.7.4.201502262128.pom
Download jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr/3.5.2/antlr-3.5.2.pom
```

And so on..........

Answer (score -1):

This command will force rebuild the whole Android project, therefore it download libraries according to the dependencies in grade file.

If there's no change on native side, you can simply open the app and run

```
 npm start
```

in the project folder, to start packager without rebuild the whole project.